# Selenium test closing window dialog

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm using Selenium with Robot Framework to write my GUI tests. One of the tests is verifying if, when the user clicks on the Close window/tab button (outside of the webpage), it triggers the alert box before exiting.

I've tried the keywords "Close window" and "Close browser", but both of them ignore the event and close the window. I also tried to close the window with javacript `window.close();`, but it doesn't work for windows that aren't opened with `window.open();` - it is a security measure. I'm using Selenium Grid with different browsers on Linux and Windows, but everytime is failing. Is there a possibility to check this with selenium or I have to use other tools like AutoIT that automate any GUI, not only the browser?

Comment: Possibly I have something in my mind to cater to your requirement but I can implement that in `Java` only, can't comment _How to_ through **Robot Framework**

Comment: @DebanjanB can you explain your solution in Java? Maybe we can think of something similar, or make an implementation in python (and contribute it eventually in the RF library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After five days of searching for a solution, I didn't find one that tries to close the page/tab/window and triggers that alert confirmation box.

Instead, I found a workaround that is similar to that and also triggers the necessary alert which is captured by Selenium: click on a link, reopen the same page or go to another one. Like this:

```
Go To           https://stackoverflow.com/
Handle Alert    action=DISMISS
```

I put here `action=DISMISS` to simply continue with my test on the same page, but if there is need you can change it to something else.